# Pushing a new instance of a table view controller object to the top of the stack while using the same nib file

Tags: objective-c, view, uitableview

I am learning how to program apps in ios.  Anyone out there know of a recent tutorial that shows how to push a new instance of a table view controller object on top of the stack without the need to create and hookup new nib?

I found an old tutorial at iphone SDK Articles dated 3/2009. The website does not exist anymore as its domain expired. But the article, using a pre-packaged 2009 "Navigation-Based Application" in xcode, shows how to drill down a table using the same view controller rather than incorporate a new  nib file. In the article, the view controller is identified as a "rootview" controller.

I have managed to modify the code to populate the data from the plist to a table cell using a UIViewController class with UITableViewDelegate and UI TableViewDataSource.  This was not difficult to do.  However, my problems begin when a cell is activated with the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  The tutorial's code creates a new instance of the same table view controller class, updates the cell data and pushes it to the top of the stack to effect the "drill down."  When I apply the same method to my controller class, xcode throws an error.  Admittedly, my ignorance is the likely cause of the problem.  That is why I am looking for help.

The tutorial code implementing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
//RootViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Get the children of the present item.
NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];


if([Children count] == 0) {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    [dvController release];

} else {

    //Prepare to tableview.

    RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Increment the Current View
    rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

    //Set the title;
    rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

    rvController.tableDataSource = Children;

    [rvController release];

}

}
```

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to instantiate a navigation controller object in the app delegate.  Self.navigationController does not work unless there is a navigation controller in play.  I have since updated the code to work with storyboards by utilizing the UIStoryboard class.

I feel like I am slowly climbing Mt. Everest with every little step.  It's painful for a new programmer (I make my living as an attorney) but somehow I seem to be moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure since you didn't post the actual error message.
One thing that may be an issue is that you pass Children to your new controller after pushing it to the stack. Therefore, some of the ViewController's view life cycle methods have probably already been called, and if you tried to do something on Children before it was set, that may crash the application.
Change it to :

```
rvController.tableDataSource = Children;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
```

Something else that may help : add an exception breakpoint in Xcode and set it to catch All exceptions on throw (I believe this is the default setting).
Should it crash because of something you wrote, the application will break on the actual line posing problem, which may help you understand the issue.

If this doesn't not help, as said before, be sure to post the actual error message.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble shooting tip.  I read more about self.navigationcontroller and realized that I did not instantiate a navigation controller in the app delegate file.  Therefore, there was no controller in place to push the new tableview instance to the top of the stack.  Duh...   I recently updated the code to work with storyboards and can achieve the same result though had to dump initWithNibName and make use of a new class UIStoryboard that provides a similar method.